# jquery script to select previous brother

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

hi im using jquery mobile this is the code

```
    <form class="ui-filterable">
        <input id="filterBasic-input" data-type="search">
    </form>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h2><span>paris</span><span class="pays">france</span> 
    <a  class="gene02"data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">generique</a></h2>
        <p>code:24</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h2><span>marakeche</span>
            <span class="pays">maroc</span>
            <a class="gene02"data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">generique</a>
        </h2>
        <p>code:3300</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

i want wen i click on class="gene02" it will take a valu of a precedent span with class pays and put it on a form class="ui-filterable"  i try to do this form class ui-filterable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".gene02").click(function () {
        $("#filterBasic-input").val($(".pays").html());
    });
});
```

but it only select france not maroc in second div . thx for help

Comment: Heard parents and child, but I liked this *select previous brother* :)

Comment: `$(this).prev(".pays").text();` is what you need. Dont use `.ready()` in jQM.

Answer (score 0):

Basically from a `class selector` or a `collection` of elements, if you access any of its properties/values, it will return the value of the `first one` in the collection only.

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".gene02").click(function() {
    var xOutput = '';
    $('.pays').each(function(){ xOutput += $(this).html(); }); 
    $("#filterBasic-input").val(xOutput);
 });
});
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".gene02").click(function() {      
    $("#filterBasic-input").val($(this).closest('div').find('.pays').html());
  });
});
```

Comment: thx but this select all .pays value   i want to select only the brother for eatch div

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like:

```
$(".gene02").click(function() 
{
    var $brotha = $(this).parent().find(".pays");
    //$brotha is your element
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p7ENh/

http://jsfiddle.net/p7ENh/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".gene02").click(function () {
    $("#filterBasic-input").val($(this).prevAll(".pays").html());
});
```

If it's always the first previous sibling you can also use `$(this).prev()` instead.